# A single word to represent a sequence of repeating numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, definition

I asked this question on [english.stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138699/what-do-you-call-a-sequence-of-repeating-numbers) too.

> What is a **noun** to represent *a sequence of repeating numbers?*

For example:

```
777777777
```

Comment: For your example, do you mean the *sequence* $7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7$; or the *integer* $777,777,777$?

Comment: To be precise, *a finite sequence of repeating natural numbers*. So it would be something like `(3, 3, 3, 3, 3)`

Comment: Then I second the suggestion of "constant sequence" below.

Comment: I should have clarified I was looking for a single word. Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: nine sevens.  (Or for Star Trek fans, nine of seven.)

Comment: You could build a portmanteau of constant + sequence = consequence, but such a neologism would likely bring with it certain repercussions...

Comment: I propose isodigital.  Except it is an adjective, and I just made it up.

Comment: Note that if you were asking about the number 777777777, you would be thinking about [repdigits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repdigit).

Answer (score 1):

I would call it a "constant sequence", but I won't claim that is definitive.

Answer (score 0):

A *run* (of sevens, or whatever).